# Stop duplicate prompt after two strings entered into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

When more than one string is entered on one line, the program prints "Enter Strings" an extra time.  For example, I enter "One Two" it prompts "Enter Strings" 2 times.  If I enter "One Two Three" it prompts "Enter Strings" 3 times and so on.  Is there anyway to fix this without creating a new object in the loop?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] x = new String[1000];
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                System.out.println ("Enter Strings");
                x[i] = kb.next();
                if (x[i].equals("done")) 
                    break;
                i++;
            }
            for (i = i - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  //prints strings in reverse order prior to done     
                System.out.println(x[i]);
            }
        }
}
    /*Example Output:
    Enter Strings
    One Two
    Enter Strings
    Enter Strings
    Hello
    Enter Strings
    Bye
    Enter Strings
    done
    Bye
    Hello
    Two
    One*/
```

Answer (score 5):

It's prompting `Enter Strings` every loop.  If you enter 3 tokens (separated by space), then it will run through the loop 3 times, reading each value immediately.

If you want one prompt, no matter how many tokens/words you enter, then read the whole line with [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29):

```
x[i] = kb.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter as many strings as you want without "Enter strings" prompt, till you enter "done". Use Scanner.hasNext() to accept more strings without prompt.

```
    System.out.println("Enter Strings");
    while(kb.hasNext()){
        x[i] = kb.next();
        if (x[i].equals("done")) 
            break;          
        i++;
    }
```